# Creating text file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I'm beginner to using Python. It's hard to study alone.
I collected data from twitter. And I can see data through IPython Console(Spyder). I want to print data to text file, but it doesn't work. My code is follow that. What should I do for printing data to text file?

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

consumer_key = ''
consumer_skey = ''
access_token = ''
access_stoken = ''

class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):
def on_data(self, data):
    print (data)
    return data
def on_err(self, status):
    print (status)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_skey)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_stoken)
twitterStreaming = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStreaming.filter(track=(["siri"]))

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.to_csv(r'C:/Users/ID500/Desktop/Sentiment analysis/hi.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Comment: I changed the code like that. But it doesn't work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the text file and write the data to it and then close it, you don't need to use Pandas for that. Also, your class listner is not formatted properly.

Here's the code that you need to modify.

```
class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

  def on_data(self, data):
      print (data)
      # write to file here.
      out_file = open("FILE_PATH_HERE", 'a')
      out_file.write(data)
      out_file.close()
      return data
  def on_err(self, status):
      print (status)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. It can be successful! Thank you.